# can someone please explain this line of code?

Tags: python, arrays, list-comprehension

The idea of it is to get any name from `nombres` that start with any letter that is given by `padron` and save it into `nombres_filtrados` (which i can't understand)
I would really appreciate the help!

```
    padron = ['A', 'E', 'J', 'T']

    nombres = ['Tamara', 'Marcelo', 'Martin', 'Juan', 'Alberto', 'Exequiel',
               'Alejandro', 'Leonel', 'Antonio', 'Omar', 'Antonia', 'Amalia',
               'Daniela', 'Sofia', 'Celeste', 'Ramon', 'Jorgelina', 'Anabela', "X"]
   
    nombres_filtrados = [x for x in nombres if any(f in x for f in padron)]

    print(nombres_filtrados)
```

Thanks!

Comment: This code does not perform what you intend. It'll add any word in `nombres` which has at least one of the characters of `padron` in it.

Comment: I thought so but the output is the following

['Tamara', 'Juan', 'Alberto', 'Exequiel', 'Alejandro', 'Antonio', 'Antonia', 'Amalia', 'Jorgelina', 'Anabela']

Comment: That's a coincidence because the names you have all start with capital letters. If you had, for example `"CELESTE"` in your `nombres` list it would be selected as well. The correct implementation would be `[x for x in nombres if x[0].upper() in padron]`.

Comment: This only works because `padron` has all capital letters and the only characters with caps on is the first character. Not the way the code should be written.

Comment: It should be `any(x.startswith(f) for f in padron)`

Comment: Out of all the names in that list, the coolest one is definitely `"X"`.  If I have another child, I'm naming them X (and citing StackOverflow on their birth certificate of course).

Comment: @paddy Make sure that they become a [professor of something](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Professor_X).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

nombres_filtrados Checks each letter in each name against your padron list, really what it should be is:

```
padron = ['A', 'E', 'J', 'T']
nombres = ['Tamara', 'Marcelo', 'Martin', 'Juan', 'Alberto', 'Exequiel',
       'Alejandro', 'Leonel', 'Antonio', 'Omar', 'Antonia', 'Amalia',
       'Daniela', 'Sofia', 'Celeste', 'Ramon', 'Jorgelina', 'Anabela', "X",'eA']

nombres_filtrados = [x for x in nombres if any(f in x[0] for f in padron)]
print(nombres_filtrados)
```

Basically what nombres_filtrados is doing is:

```
padron = ['A', 'E', 'J', 'T']
nombres = ['Tamara', 'Marcelo', 'Martin', 'Juan', 'Alberto', 'Exequiel',
       'Alejandro', 'Leonel', 'Antonio', 'Omar', 'Antonia', 'Amalia',
       'Daniela', 'Sofia', 'Celeste', 'Ramon', 'Jorgelina', 'Anabela', "X",'eA']

nombres_filtrados = [x for x in nombres if any(f in x[0] for f in padron)]


output = []
for name in nombres:        #For Each Name in Nombres
    if name[0] in padron:   #if the First Letter is In Padron
        output.append(name) #Save To Our Output

print(output)
```

Answer (score 1):

It is useless to test all letters of the names. An efficient method would be to match only the first letter against a set:

```
[name for name in nombres
 if name[0].upper() in set(padron)]
```

Output:

```
['Tamara',
 'Juan',
 'Alberto',
 'Exequiel',
 'Alejandro',
 'Antonio',
 'Antonia',
 'Amalia',
 'Jorgelina',
 'Anabela']
```